# Binding to item in ObservableCollection from code

Tags: wpf, binding, observablecollection

i have an ObservableCollection which contains 0 - 200 items.
Every time when a user add items to the Collection, a label is created in my canvas, the label content is = the new item in my Collection and can be edited by users.

For now i create the Bindigs from code like:

```
Binding myBinding1 = new Binding();
myBinding.Path = new propertyPath("MYCollection[0]");
myLabel1.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, myBinding);

Binding myBinding2 = new Binding();
myBinding.Path = new propertyPath("MYCollection[1]");
myLabel2.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, myBinding);

Binding myBinding3 = new Binding();
myBinding.Path = new propertyPath("MYCollection[2]");
myLabel3.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, myBinding);
```

But when i delete the second item in my Collection the bindings for myLabel3 are gone.

Is there a way to Bind the LabelContent like this?

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();
myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(MYCollection[0]);
myLabel.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, myBinding);
```

Or have i to update all my bindings when an item is deleted?

Comment: This is not the way of WPF. Create ItemControl in Canvas and use ItemTemplate to create specific labels, binding through XAML. You want to bind against item, not against index.

Comment: Never heard of the ItemsControl (new to WPF), but this is exactly what i need. Thank you very much!